# BOBF enable and disable of actions

Tags: sapui5

​We have Developed an application using BOPF. We have built a UI5 List report over it. We have enabled multiselect feature in the list page. Now I want to enable and disable the button if I select multiple entries accordingly. But I didn't find any code how can I control it using BOPF. How can we achieve this using BOBF or UI5?

Comment: Welcome to SO ;) Please read this article on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This would include a proper description of what you are trying to achieve, your code (or the relevant snippets) as well as your efforts showing what you have tried so far and possible error messages. It is also advisable to provide a full [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)..

Comment: Never done much with BOBF but the oData service is based on CDS right? You could look into annotations perhaps

Comment: Yes OData is based on CDS. But annotations are not there for multiple selection on table. Thus it Doesn't give us condition based enabling or disabling